# Custom CSS code doesn't work with Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

For example I'm trying to set body background color in style.css, but code doesn't work.
My link to Bootstrap 5 and custom CSS:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

This code doesn't work:

```
body {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

Only Bootstrap class works for me:

```
<body class = "bg-black">
```

I was trying to add !important after background-color but it didn't helped. Similar questions haven't solved my problem yet.

Comment: That style looks like it should work, can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to see the issue ourselves?

Comment: I just simply created css folder and put my style.css into and it works well now with href="css/style.css". Before it was in the same folder with my index file but it should work anyway. Maybe it was just bugged and I was struggling with the problem couple of days.

Comment: Its because The inline style has higher priority than the !important

Comment: Not reproducible https://codeply.com/p/CcgSgVmuc9 you don't need !important either

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to error:404 which means browser did not find the specified file.
Add the correct path to solve the issue.
For example if you have a folder 'webfiles' and CSS file in one level and html code is inside 'webfiles', you should use `../`
The link will be

```
../style.css
```

Note that your link to CSS file should be below all Bootstrap style link.